# select All/deselect all checkbox in Datatable JSF without using Javascript

Tags: jsf

I am making datatable in JSF using (dataTable tag).

I am having several rows in that with check box( selectBooleanCheckbox ) in front of every record.
I have commandLink button for selecting all check box and deselected all check box..

i am trying to select/unselect all checkboxes in the datatable using a single commandLink. As I am trying to set it on the server, I am unable to do so. I have looked around for solutions but could not get how to accomplish on the server side.
thnks

Comment: Thnx !i am glad to have your valuable response but..i have gone through it..and i need pure backingbean support..

Comment: the above problem i have found solution

Comment: jsf part
<a4j:commandLink action="#{bean.selectall}"
                                             render="datatabel"  title="select All" execute="@this">

in datatable

<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selectall" name="selectall"
                                                     value="#{Bean.Map[datatable .id]}"/>
                               <h:graphicImage url=""/>
                             </a4j:commandLink>

bean Side
initialize the map with default...at first..this i achieved this